# How do I copy specific records from one table into another table using adf dataflow

Tags: azure-data-factory, google-cloud-dataflow

I need to create a table which stores the records of all the table names and their row count in a database.

I tried creating a data flow where I selected the specific data out using transformation.and was able to generate the output for one single table. I had planned to integrate it into a pipeline and use a for each activity to transform each table but I'm unable to append those records into a new table

Answer (score 0):

> I need to create a table which stores the records of all the table names and their row count in a database.

You can use copy activity to achieve your requirement. Use the below query referred from this [MS Ask](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/862070/how-to-get-list-of-tables-and-count-of-rows-from-t) by @[Dan Guzman](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/users/na/?userid=24316e1e-c50f-4cf3-ac7e-519b7d517c0a) in copy activity source query to get the table names and the row count.

```
SELECT s.name AS SchemaName, t.name AS TableName, SUM(p.rows) AS TableRowCount FROM sys.schemas AS s JOIN sys.tables AS t ON t.schema_id = s.schema_id JOIN sys.partitions AS p ON p.object_id = t.object_id GROUP BY s.name, t.name ORDER BY SchemaName, TableName;
```

[image]

Give your target table dataset in the copy activity sink and execute the pipeline. The desired output will look like this.

[image]

Here, my target table is in the same database and it has no rows before the pipeline run.

If your source database is not SQL and if you want to do this only with a dataflow, then first you need to get the table names list from a query and use that in lookup. Give that lookup output to a ForEach.

Take the dataflow activity inside this ForEach and you need to pass the table names as parameter to the dataflow. Use this parameter in the dataflow query like `"select '{$param1}' as name, count(*) as count from {product}"` and give your target table dataset in the dataflow sink.
This will insert the table name and rows into the target table in each iteration.